# Swift: failing to copy files to a newly created folder

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I'm building a simple program in Swift, it should copy files with a certain extension to a different folder. If this folder exist the program will just copy them in the folder, if the folder doesn't exist, the program has to make it first.

```
let newMTSFolder = folderPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MTS Files")

if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(newMTSFolder)) {
    fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(newMTSFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)
}

while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
    if element.hasSuffix("MTS") { // checks the extension
        var fullElementPath = folderPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(element)

        println("copy \(fullElementPath) to \(newMTSFolder)")

        var err: NSError?
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(fullElementPath, toPath: newMTSFolder, error: &err) {
            println("\(fullElementPath) file added to the folder.")
        } else {
            println("FAILED to add \(fullElementPath) to the folder.")
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code will correctly identify the MTS files but then result in a "FAILED to add...", what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [`copyItemAtPath(...)` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407903-copyitem):

> `dstPath`
>   The path at which to place the copy of `srcPath`. This path must
>   include the name of the file or directory in its new location. ...

You have to append the file name to the destination directory for the
`copyItemAtPath()` call (code updated for Swift 3 and later)

```
let srcURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fullElementPath)
let destURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: newMTSFolder).appendingPathComponent(srcURL.lastPathComponent)

do {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: destURL)
} catch {
    print("copy failed:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```