# Swift 3 File copy error

Tags: swift, url, nsfilemanager

I am trying to make a copy of a .plist into the Documents folder.
I have this code but I get "File copy error".

```
let srcPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Gameboard", ofType: "plist")
//let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
let path = String(describing: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first)
print(srcPath)
print(path)
do {
    //Copy the project plist file to the documents directory.
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: srcPath!, toPath: path)
} catch {
    print("File copy error!")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25291115/1187415.

Comment: `FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath:, toPath:)` doesn't throw an error that could give you hints on the issue?

Comment: Never use `String(describing)` to convert a `URL` to a `String`. Use the proper `URL` method (`path` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407903-copyitem):

> **dstPath** 
>   The path at which to place the copy of srcPath. This path must include the name of the file or directory in its new location. This parameter must not be nil.

You need to append the file name `"Gameboard.plist"` to the destination path:

```
let srcUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Gameboard", ofType: "plist")
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(
    for: .documentDirectory,
    in: .userDomainMask
).first!
let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(
   "Gameboard.plist",   // or srcUrl.lastPathComponent
    isDirectory: false
)

do {
   try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcUrl, to: destinationUrl)
} catch {
   ...
}
```