# How to access created Directory? - NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I am trying to create a new directory and put files into it. However, I'm getting

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Offline” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
```

I am able to create this new directory and the file exists.

```
let offlinePath = fileDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Offline")
try? fileManager.createDirectory(at: offlinePath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

files.forEach { file in
    if let localUrl = file.localUrl {
      do {
          try fileManager.moveItem(at: localUrl, to: offlinePath)
          file.localUrl = offlinePath
      } catch {
          print(error)
      }
 }
```

Comment: What is `fileDirectory`?

Comment: @vadian fileDirectory is a URL where I am storing my files

Comment: I know it's an URL but what is the location?

Comment: @JoshCaswell not sure what you mean by sandboxing. This is on iOS

Comment: Essentially the same issue as in [Swift: failing to copy files to a newly created folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291115/swift-failing-to-copy-files-to-a-newly-created-folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move a file to a directory without appending the file name

```
do {
    let fileName = localUrl.lastPathComponent
    let offlineURL = offlinePath.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    try fileManager.moveItem(at: localUrl, to: offlineURL)
    file.localUrl = offlineURL
} ...
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks, I wish the error was more clear.

Comment: Actually it's quite clear: *The **file** “Offline”...*